# What is the best way to add lagged features for time-series predictions with a long prediction period?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, lags

I am currently dealing with a time-series problem and want to add lag feature(s) to my data. The point is, that I should predict 1 month of daily sales based on 4 months of training data. So if I add for example a lag feature by shifting the data by 1 day, this can't help me for my predictions because I just have this information for the first day in my test data..
Any suggestions what is the best way to deal with this problem?
I am thankful for any advice! :-)